# Ruby high CPU Usage Even using ELB with 2 M3.large type Instance in AWS why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cpu-usage, rds

I am using EC2 servers (with 2 instances m3.large type in Elastic Load Balancer) with Ruby on Rails3 installed for API calls and Database RDS(Mysql), I created an alarm in AWS for my instance CPU Utilization greater than 80%.
I am getting High CPU Utilization issue by mail since one week, and many of my app users are not even log in or signup that time due to this issue.

I used top command to find out the process, where I found the Ruby command is responsible for 100% CPU usage, below is the detail of top command -

> `user  ec2-user    %CPU  100     Command  ruby`

please help me how it can be solved.

Comment: Have you try to implement auto scaling?

Comment: No, I have not implemented auto-scaling.